# Understanding the difference between character matching and token matching

Tags: java, mysql, solr, lucene, full-text-search

What is the difference between search features implemented using substring/character matching and search features implemented using token based matching? I'm looking for an intuitive and not-too-technical explanation for product planning purposes. Below is my explanation, is more or less correct, but not intuitive or complete.

The answer has to do with what you choose to be the smallest unit of match: are you matching individual characters, or are you matching individual words? Examples of substring matching:

```
"lady's hat".contains("l") == true
"lady's hat".contains("lady's hat") == true
```

Whereas token matching might be something like:

```
Array("lady", "s", "hat").contains("l") == false
Array("lady", "s", "hat").contains("lady") == true
Array("lady", "s", "hat").contains("lady's hat") == false
```

Obviously this is a gross oversimplification and begs lots of questions. I think I might be trying to explain the problem at the wrong level of abstraction.

*Context: I am working in Java on search and filtering features for a web application. Our current approach uses the `LIKE` operator and MySQL, and suffers from the obvious performance problem of a full table scan. We are considering using Lucene, Solr, or denormalizing our relational data.*

Answer (score 1):

**Character matching**
Character matching is expensive and will always be O(NP) where N=number of characters to search and P=number of terms to search for.

This is the pseduo-code for the linear search:

```
function linear_search(items, terms, match_mode) {
  matched_items = new array();
  for(item_idx=0, item_count=count(items);item_idx < item_count;++item_idx) {
      doc = items[item_idx];
      match_count = 0;
      for(term_idx=0, term_count=count(terms);term_idx < term_count;++term_idx) {
          term = terms[term_idx];
          for(i=0, doc_len = strlen(doc), term_len = strlen(term) ; i < doc_len; i += term_len) {
              if(substr(doc, i, term_len) == term) { 
                  if(mode == 'ANY') {
                      matched_items[]=item_idx;
                      continue 3;
                  }  
                  ++match_count;
                  break;
              }
          }
       }
       if(mode == 'ALL' && (match_count == count(items)) matched_items[]=item_idx;
  }
  return matched_items;
}
```

Each document(row) must be searched using the linear search operation, so N is actually sum(strlen(N)) over the data set (each row, aka a document is an N).  O(NP) is a very long operation for large documents, or many documents, or both.

**Inverted indexes (token searching)**
Token based searches on the other hand pre-parse the data into tokens and create an "inverted index".  Each document (the text to be searched) is first broken into terms, then the terms are indexed and point to documents.
For example, given the raw data:

```
1, the quick brown fox
2, all cows eat grass
3, all the world
```

An inverted index is created:

```
all => 2, 3
brown => 1
cows => 2
eat => 2
fox => 1
grass => 2
quick => 1
the => 1, 3
world => 3
```

A b-tree is usually created over the tokens.  A lookup of a token is therefore O(log(N)) to get the list of documents that match the token.  A lookup to get the actual data is usually another O(log(N)) operation.
This results in an inverted index operation costing, assuming b-tree structures:

```
O(log(TERM_COUNT)) + O(log(DOC_MATCH_COUNT))
```

**Word position analysis**
Usually the index will store word position in the document, along with the document matched.  This allows positional analysis, such as 'foo' near 'bar' without consulting the documents themselves:

```
all => 2:1, 3:1
brown => 1:3
cows => 2:2
eat => 2:3
fox => 1:4
grass => 2:4
quick => 1:2
the => 1:1, 3:2
world => 3:3
```

**stemming**
In addition, "stemming", such as the Porter Stemmer(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) is usually applied to the terms before indexing and before searching.

A stemmer will convert words like 'branded' and 'branding' to 'brand' such that a search for brand will return documents matching branded or branding or brand.